# Why does Datastore throw exception parsing the arguments to URLFETCH?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-flexible

Running a simple query using Google Cloud API for Datastore in a background thread in a "backend" Google App Engine Flexible Environment instance,  I got the following exception on multiple query attempts for a few seconds.

```
An error occurred parsing (locally or remotely) the arguments to URLFETCH.Fetch()
```

(See below for stacktrace.)

It came at the same time as another error

```
com.google.apphosting.vmruntime.VmApiProxyDelegate  convertApiResponseRpcErrorToException: RPC failed, API=urlfetch.Fetch : BAD_REQUEST : There is no active request context for this API call.
```

Right before the exception, the logs show

```
 com.google.apphosting.vmruntime.VmRequestThreadFactory interruptRequestThreads: Request thread Thread-16 is still alive, forcing interrupt.
```

and

```
... convertApiResponseRpcErrorToException: RPC failed, API=urlfetch.Fetch : CANCELLED
```

This would suggest that a Google App Engine timeout was reached, such as the 60 second limit on web requests. Looking at the logs, that does not seem to be the true. But regardless, that query runs in a background thread created with *backgroundThreadFactory*.

This is Java code that I ran earlier and later, on the same data, with no such problems, so something specific happened at runtime

What can cause this problem?

Stacktrace:

```
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by: com.google.cloud.datastore.DatastoreException: com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy$ArgumentException: An error occurred parsing (locally or remotely) the arguments to URLFETCH.Fetch(). at com.google.cloud.datastore.DatastoreException.translateAndThrow(DatastoreException.java:66) at com.google.cloud.datastore.DatastoreImpl.runQuery(DatastoreImpl.java:97) at com.google.cloud.datastore.QueryResultsImpl.sendRequest(QueryResultsImpl.java:73) at com.google.cloud.datastore.QueryResultsImpl.<init>(QueryResultsImpl.java:57) at com.google.cloud.datastore.DatastoreImpl.run(DatastoreImpl.java:82) at com.google.cloud.datastore.DatastoreImpl.run(DatastoreImpl.java:73) at com.freightos.backup.datastore.gcloudapi.GCloudApiDSBackup.loadEntity(GCloudApiDSBackup.java:692) at com.freightos.backup.datastore.gcloudapi.GCloudApiDSBackup$CopyEntities.loadOneEntity(GCloudApiDSBackup.java:1104) ... 7 more Caused by: com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy$ArgumentException: An error occurred parsing (locally or remotely) the arguments to URLFETCH.Fetch(). at com.google.apphosting.vmruntime.VmApiProxyDelegate.convertApiResponseRpcErrorToException(VmApiProxyDelegate.java:397) at com.google.apphosting.vmruntime.VmApiProxyDelegate.convertRemoteError(VmApiProxyDelegate.java:341) at com.google.apphosting.vmruntime.VmApiProxyDelegate.runSyncCall(VmApiProxyDelegate.java:187) at com.google.apphosting.vmruntime.VmApiProxyDelegate.makeApiCall(VmApiProxyDelegate.java:155) at com.google.apphosting.vmruntime.VmApiProxyDelegate.makeSyncCallWithTimeout(VmApiProxyDelegate.java:143) at com.google.apphosting.vmruntime.VmApiProxyDelegate.makeSyncCall(VmApiProxyDelegate.java:132) at com.google.apphosting.vmruntime.VmApiProxyDelegate.makeSyncCall(VmApiProxyDelegate.java:75) at com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy.makeSyncCall(ApiProxy.java:118) at com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.URLFetchServiceImpl.fetch(URLFetchServiceImpl.java:40) at com.google.api.client.extensions.appengine.http.UrlFetchRequest.execute(UrlFetchRequest.java:74) at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:981) at com.google.datastore.v1.client.RemoteRpc.call(RemoteRpc.java:87) at com.google.datastore.v1.client.Datastore.runQuery(Datastore.java:108) at com.google.cloud.datastore.spi.DefaultDatastoreRpc.runQuery(DefaultDatastoreRpc.java:158) at com.google.cloud.datastore.DatastoreImpl$1.call(DatastoreImpl.java:93) at com.google.cloud.datastore.DatastoreImpl$1.call(DatastoreImpl.java:89) at com.google.cloud.RetryHelper.doRetry(RetryHelper.java:179) at com.google.cloud.RetryHelper.runWithRetries(RetryHelper.java:244) at com.google.cloud.datastore.DatastoreImpl.runQuery(DatastoreImpl.java:88) ... 13 more
```